# Pagination Not working in my Codeigniter

Tags: codeigniter

this is my controller file and its not working
controller name blog
model name blogmodel
view file name loggedin

```
function getvalues(){
    $config['base_url'] = 'http://192.168.1.50/codeigni/index.php/blog/getvalues';
$config['total_rows'] = 200;
$config['per_page'] = 20;

$this->pagination->initialize($config);

echo $this->pagination->create_links();
    $this->load->model('blogmodel');
    $data['results']=$this->blogmodel->getall();    
    $this->load->view('Login/loggedin',$data);      
    }
    }
```

this is my model file and model name 'blogmodel'

```
 function getall(){
    $query=$this->db->query("SELECT * FROM user_details");
   return $query->result();
                    }
}
```

this is my view file i cannot access pagination

```
   <p><?php echo $links; ?></p><?php

    echo "<table border='1'>
    <tr>
    <th>id</th>
    <th>username</th>
    <th>password</th>
    <th>email</th>

    </tr>";
foreach($results as $row){
    echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td>" .$row->id;  
    echo "<td>". $row->username;
    echo "<td>". $row->password;
    echo "<td>". $row->email;
    echo "</tr>";
    }
    echo "</table>";
    ?>
```

Comment: Then fix it. How can we help if we don't know why 'it's not working'. You need to elaborate a bit.

Comment: its fixed it provide error name

Comment: Message: Undefined variable: links

Filename: Login/loggedin.php

Comment: You have an undefined variable. What else do you need to know that PHP isn't already telling you?

Comment: I'm not going to respond to that... Lol

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of doing `echo $this->pagination->create_links();`

do as below

```
$data["links"] = $this->pagination->create_links();
```